# How to create typings for ts

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8, typescript-typings

I have a library installed in `node_modules/` and I want a fast hack so I can use it in typescript app. In folder `typings/modules` I created a folder with the name of the module and an `index.d.ts` file. Inside that file I have

```
declare module "lib-name" {
  export default class Logger {
    constructor(namespace: string)
  }
}
```

I'm able to import the module, but when I try to `let l = new Lib('namespace');` I'm getting error `cannot use 'with' an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should have `class` in your typings. It is an interface contract you should declare.

Moreover the documentation says that the new expression needs a `new` method in the interface : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html

Try something like this maybe :

```
declare module "lib-name" {
  interface Logger {
    new (namespace: string): Logger
  }

  export var Logger: Logger;
}
```